# ChartJS - [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')]] Error when navigating back to page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, chartjs

I am having an issue whereby the pie chart loads upon refreshing the page, but when I leave the page and come back I get the below:

[LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')]]

[image: Chart loads when refreshing page]

I have tried using conditional templates but then the chart does not load even in the first instance.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<template>
<div class="cs-container">
    <lightning-card title="Customer Service Information" icon-name="standard:case">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-child 1">
                <lightning-card title='Cases by Type' icon-name="utility:chart">
                        <div class="chart-wrapper">
                            <canvas id="chart" class="donut" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
                        </div>
                     <!--   <div if:false={isChartJsInitialized}>
                            Chart not loaded yet.
                        </div> -->
                </lightning-card>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-child 2">
                <lightning-card title='Case Details' icon-name="utility:table">
                   <!-- <template if:true={anyCases}> -->
                        <div style="height: 200px;">
                            <lightning-datatable
                                    key-field="id"
                                    data={records}
                                    columns={columns}
                                    hide-checkbox-column="true">
                            </lightning-datatable>
                        </div>
                 <!--   </template> 
                    <template if:false={anyCases}>
                        <div class="slds-text-heading_medium">No cases to display.</div>
                    </template> -->
                </lightning-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</div>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
importing the Chart library from Static resources
import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ChartJs'; 
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

import getCasesList from '@salesforce/apex/AccountsCasesDashboardController.getCasesList';
import getCasesByType from '@salesforce/apex/AccountsCasesDashboardController.getCasesByType';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Case Number', fieldName: 'CaseNumber' },
    { label: 'Case Name', fieldName: 'Case_Name__c' },
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status' },
    { label: 'Type', fieldName: 'RecordTypeName'},
];

export default class AccountsCasesDashboard extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    records = [];
    columns = columns
    //@api anyCases = false;
    @track chartjsInitialized;
    //@track caseTypes;

    @wire(getCasesList, {recordIdAccount: '$recordId'}) wiredCases ({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('data 1 - ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data.length > 0) { 
                this.anyCases = true;
            }
            let tempRecords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            tempRecords = tempRecords.map((row) => {
                return { 
                  ...row,
                  ContactName: row.Contact.Name,
                  AccountName: row.Account.Name,
                  UnitName: row.Plot__r.Name,
                  RecordTypeName: row.RecordType.Name,
                };
              });
              this.records =  tempRecords;
        } else if (error) { 
            this.error = error; 
        }   
    }

    @wire (getCasesByType, {recordIdAccount: '$recordId'}) cases ( {error, data}) {
        if(data) {
            console.log('data - ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            for(var key in data) {
                this.updateChart(data[key].count,data[key].label);
            }
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.cases = undefined;
        }
    }

    chart;
    chartjsInitialized = false;
    config={
    type : 'doughnut',
    data :{
    datasets :[
    {
    data: [
    ],
    backgroundColor :[
        'rgb(255,99,132)',
        'rgb(255,159,64)',
        'rgb(255,205,86)',
        'rgb(75,192,192)',
    ],
       label:'Dataset 1'
    }
    ],
    labels:[]
    },
    options: {
        responsive : true,
    legend : {
        position :'right'
    },
    animation:{
       animateScale: true,
       animateRotate : true
    }
    }
    };
    renderedCallback()
    {
       if(this.chartjsInitialized)
      {
       return;
      }
      this.chartjsInitialized = true;
      Promise.all([
       loadScript(this,chartjs)
      ]).then(() =>{
        const ctx = this.template.querySelector('canvas.donut').getContext('2d');
        this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);
      }).catch(error => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
        title : 'Error loading ChartJS',
        message : error.message,
        variant : 'error',
       }),
      );
    });
    }
    updateChart(count,label)
    {
       this.chart.data.labels.push(label);
       this.chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
       dataset.data.push(count);
       });
       this.chart.update();
     }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public with sharing class AccountsCasesDashboardController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Case> getCasesList(String recordIdAccount) {
        List<Case> caseList= [ SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Case_Name__c, Status, Contact.Name, Account.Name, Plot__r.Name, Contact.AccountId, RecordType.Name
                               FROM Case 
                               WHERE Contact.AccountId =: recordIdAccount ];
        return caseList;
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<DataSet> getCasesByType(String recordIdAccount){

        List<AggregateResult> result =  [ SELECT Count(Id) cnt, RecordType.Name //Contact.AccountId
                                          FROM CASE 
                                          WHERE Contact.AccountId =: recordIdAccount 
                                          GROUP BY RecordType.Name ];

        List<DataSet> dataSet = new List<DataSet>();

        for(AggregateResult ar:result){

            String status =  (String)ar.get('Name') ;

            Integer total =(Integer)ar.get('cnt');

            dataSet.add(new DataSet(status ,total));
        }
        System.debug('dataSet'+dataSet);
        return dataSet ;
    }

    public class DataSet {
    
        public DataSet(String label ,Integer count){
            this.label  = label ;
            this.count = count ;
        }

        @AuraEnabled
        public String label {get;set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public Integer  count {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?